# Laravel 4 Polymorphic Relationship with Namespaced Models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I created an Seo table with Eloquent's polymorphic relationship. So for Seo table, I have something like this

```
title
description
seoble_id
seoble_type
timestamps
```

Then for all the models that will have custom SEO, I added the morphOne relationship while the Seo model will have morphMany relationship. So for Post model I will have something like this

```
namespace App\Models;

class Post extends Eloquent {
  public function seo()
  {
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Seo', 'seoble');
  }
}
```

However, the relationship will only work if I the seoble_type is filled with the fully namespaced model class name. So the seoble_type must be 'App\Models\Post' (model name like 'Post' or table name like 'posts' will not work) for the polymorphic relationship to work. The problem is, if I somehow want to change the namespace, I will have to update all the seo table to update the seoble_type field, which will be a hassle.

Now, before I tried the polymorphic relationship, I usually created the equivalent table something like this:

```
title
description
object_id
type
timestamps
```

And for the relationship, for each model I will have something like this:

```
namespace App\Models;

class Post extends Eloquent {
  public function seo()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Seo', 'object_id')->where('type', 'post');
  }
}
```

My question is, are these 2 methods equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

if you using morph it mean you wish single table can be used as relations to any table with indication by object_id and type_id. so the answer for your question, is not equivalent.

I thought at your case (for save seo table) the recommended ways as my opinions is using morphOne.

and then, for your problem in morph you can fill your seoable_type with whatever do you like, not should fill with your namespace

here is simple code when using morph :

```
namespace App\Models;

class Seo extends Eloquent {

    public function seoable()
        {
           return $this->morphTo();
        }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Seo', 'seoable_id');
    }
}

/*----*/

namespace App\Models;

class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function getSeo($type)
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Seo', 'seoable');
    }
}


// you can using like this :
$seo = \Seo::where('seoable_type', 'post');
$seo->post->first();

// or like this : 
$post = \Post::with('getSeo')->findOrFail($id)->toArray();
```

wish this helped you.